# Bind button to datagrid dynamically in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have `DataGrid` as below

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Setvalue" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="6" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
</DataGrid>
```

I am binding the data to `DataGrid` as below

```
Setvalue.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
```

I want to generate buttton for each row dynamically.I have tried like this

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new
DataGridViewButtonColumn();
btn.HeaderText = "Copy";
btn.Text = "Copy";
btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
Imported.Columns.Add(btn);
```

I am getting error like "cannot convert from DataGridViewButtonColumn to DataGridColumn" . Please let me know any approach .

Comment: Create a DataGridTemplateColumn with a CellTemplate. But why are you doing this programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a `CellTemplate` in your XAML. If you want it to be the last column, you could set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `false` and define all columns in the order you want them to appear:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Setvalue" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="6" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Type}" Header="Type" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Place}" Header="Place" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="Copy" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks mm8 . How can i set column index here . like i want copy column to be appeared at the end and not at the beginning . and also how can i bind each button to respective row . Please let me know

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "column index"? Do you want the button column to appear in the middle of the other columns? And what do you want to bind it to?

Comment: I want button column to appear at the end , l mean that should be the last column .and if i click that button , i should be able to get the content of that row only .

Comment: I am not able to attach the screenshot . i have tried your solution . The copy column is coming in the begining itself . not at the end

Comment: How many other columns are there? Can't you specify them all explicitly in the XAML markup in the order you want them to appear?

Comment: In the XML i have not specified . It is binding the column directly from the datatable . In data able i have 3 column Name , Type , Place . And copy column should appear at the end

Comment: @eth_92: See my edited answer. Define all columns explicitly in the XAML.

Comment: Thanks mm8 . I am able to get it at the end , but one extra copy row is appearing .

Comment: Copy row? What is that?

Comment: I mean when there is only two row from the data table , instead of 2 copy button , 3 copy button will appear.

Comment: Set the CanUserAddNewRows property to false to prevent the extra row from showing up.

Comment: Perfect it is working . Now if i click copy button it should copy the place column content of that row . Copy function i will do but how do i bind that data on click of copy button .Please let me know

Comment: @eth_92: You should really ask another question if you have another issue but you could just hook up a Click event handler to the Button and implement it in your code-behind.

Comment: Sure mm8 , Thanks a lot